# RegEx for deleting X amount of text above and below four \r\n values

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,

Is it possible for a NotePad++ general expression to extract "X" amount of text and rows sandwiched in between for entries of \r\n located above and below? Below is the visual example as an aid:

```
UNWANTED "X" amount of text above
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
"X" amount of text and rows sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
UNWANTED "X" amount of text below
```

My goal is to have the general expression extract only whatever amount of text and rows is located in between four \r\n values and all of the UNWANTED TEXT to say behind.  Below is an example of how I need the data to paste from the clipboard into a new text file:

```
"X" amount of text and rows in sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
"X" amount of text and rows in sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
"X" amount of text and rows in sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
"X" amount of text and rows in sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above
```

The difference is all of the UNWANTED text is removed and all I have left is the data that was originally nested within four values of \r\n is now nested within three values of \r\n. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use notepad++ so I don't know if it can do group capturing, but this is how I would do it: `(\\r\\n){4}(.)+(\\r\\n){4}` replaced with `$2` (the second group, the data). Note: you may need to remove the second \ on each.

Comment: @Rhyono Yeah you can do group capturing in Notepad++ and it is very easy. The replace statement would have to be `\2`

Comment: For the Notepad++ the @Rhyono answer suits your problem with little modification: `(\r\n){4}(.)+(\r\n){4}` and if you want to create groups everything inside parentesis is a group and you count it from left to right

Comment: PSXLS, What version of NotePad++ are you using because your Regex .+?(?:\r\n){5}(.+(?:\r\n){4})\r\n.+(?:\r\n)? is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   .+?(?:\r\n){5}(.+(?:\r\n){4})\r\n.+(?:\r\n)?
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`.

This will transform the following file:

```
UNWANTED "X" amount of text above




"X" amount of text and rows sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above




UNWANTED "X" amount of text below
```

To:

```
"X" amount of text and rows sandwiched in between four entries of \r\n below and above



(we keep only 3 empty lines)
```